# Laravel - Controller not setting some variables when return using Redirect::to

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In my controller, I validate the input fields and if any validation fails I want to return back to the form and refill the previous values that the user was inputing (if there is any other easier way instead this please tell me). But here is what I'm doing:

Controller.php:

```
public function store(Request $request, AnexoController $anexoController)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(), 
        $rules, 
        $messages
    );

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to($request->headers->get('referer'))
         ->withErrors($validator)
         ->withReq($request->all());
    }

    // continues the function...
}
```

At the view.blade.php:

```
<input type="text" 
    maxlength="256" 
    id="text-input" 
    name="id" 
    placeholder="Código" 
    class="form-control" 
    @if(isset($req)) value="{{$req->id}}"
    @else value="$REQ VARIABLE NOT SET"
    @endif
    required>
```

And when I test it, the field `id` value is set to "$REQ VARIABLE NOT SET" but `$errors` from `$validator` variable is set. So, why isn't the variable `$req` being set in this context? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$request->validate([
  //rules
]);
```

It will automatically return to form page with all the errors and inputs,

In your form you'll neet do add a helper in value of inputs for old inputs

```
<input type="text" value={{ old('email')}} name="email">
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation & https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers

Comment: there is no such function "old" in this link

Comment: ohh thats just the page for validation, old is a helper function to retrieve old input data. here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers

Comment: you don't need to use `if($validator->fails())` block with `$request->validate()`